# What do sharks not like the smell of?

Tags: biochemistry, marine-biology

I was reading about the sharks strong sense of smell ( Shark senses - @EnhancedLearning.com ) and wondered if any research has been done into what they don't like the smell of?

Is there any material that they don't like being near and would stay away from?

Comment: Could you provide a link to what you were reading?

Comment: Shark senses-@EnhancedLearning.com . Maybe they could mix a deterent into surfboard wax or wetsuits (:

Comment: I don't think one can easily determine what smell sharks don't like. You know, you can't easily find whether a shark turned around from something because it didn't like its smell or it wasn't interested in it, especially [tiger sharks](http://visual.ly/tiger-shark-oceans-garbage-can) ;)

Comment: @another'Homo sapien' , if I could name one I wouldn't need to ask the question? With the advances in biotechnology and other areas in recent decades it is more than possible that we could make something that deters sharks, I think to say it doesn't exist or can't be done is very narrow minded (with all due respect it's figure of speech) .

Comment: There could be a marine creature that contains something that makes the sharks not like to eat them or see them as a snack.

Comment: @another 'Homo sapien' I was just guessing with the puffer fish I , agree this is going a bit off topic from the O.P, thank for the input anyway (: